# Best way to verify a file header

Tags: header, metadata, archive

I'm trying to verify that a file header (metadata) has the correct info and was not corrupted.

For example:
Some one manipulates the file size in the header of an archive to exploit a zero day. How do I check that the file size is actually that size?

- What is the best way to do it?

Comment: If you mean you want to calculate the length of the uncompressed stream as the decompressor would produce, this is effectively decompressing the stream. Maybe there is a decoder that will decode without writing the output, but that will depend on the archive format.

Comment: Yeah I know i have to do one for each file time but does it work to run an archive on it and if it does work, figure out if its the header? I'm still looking around though